# John and Steve are Enemy

Tags: grammaticality

Im very curious about the difference meaning of these sentences the below. I know that there are several grammatical errors on them but if non-native English speakers speak those, how do they sound like to native English speakers? Please, help me out!

1. John and Steve are the enemy.
2. John and Steve are enemies.
3. John and Steve are Enemy.

Answer (score 1):

"John and Steve are the enemy" implies that, together, John and Steve are seen by the speaker as the enemy of the speaker and some group or movement or philosophy or political stance that the speaker is associating themselves with. For example, "If you want to keep your heating bills low, faulty insulation is the enemy."

"John and Steve are enemies" typically is used to mean they are enemies of each other. But, literally speaking, it can also mean that the both of them are enemies of some other, unspecified, target.

"John and Steve are Enemy" means that John and Steve have formed a rock band that they are calling "Enemy".